# Adding identifier to json in nodejs/ejs

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

I am looking for a way to format the json I get from posting a form into an easier way to parse in nodejs. The form will correctly gather the data but I would like to have an identifier on each row.

I would like to know if it's possible from a forms post to create a json output similar to what I would like to output in the bottom. Or is there a much simpler solution to this?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="test" method="get">
            <% for( obj in data) { console.log(obj); %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="<%=data[obj].date%>" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><%=data[obj].day%> <%=data[obj].date%></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <% if(data[obj].dayNumber == 0 || data[obj].dayNumber == 6) { %>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="<%=data[obj].date%>" name="date" value="" style="background-color: grey">
                                <% } else { %>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="<%=data[obj].date%>" name="date" value="">
                                    <% } %>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<%=data[obj].month%>" name="date" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="<%=data[obj].date%>" name="date" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="<%=data[obj].username%>" name="date" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <% } %>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Spara</button>
                    </div>
        </form>
```

The /test route will generate the following output.

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    var info = req.query.date;

    console.log(util.inspect(info, { showHidden: false, depth: null }))

    res.send("Done");
});
```

Output

```
[ '3',
  '2017-08',
  '2017-08-01',
  'xxxx',
  '4',
  '2017-08',
  '2017-08-02',
  'xxxx' ]
```

But I would like it to output something like

```
{"report": {
    "2017-08-01": {
        "hours": 1,
        "month": "2017-08",
        "date": "2017-08-01,
        "username": "xxxx"
    },
"2017-08-02": {
        "hours": 1,
        "month": "2017-08",
        "date": "2017-08-02,
        "username": "xxxx"
    },
}}
```

Comment: Why don't make this json at client side itself? rather posting the form make an ajax call with the json.

Comment: Good suggestion. I opted for the other way around to parse the "non ideal" input into JSON in the node js backend.